# Torrent vs. wget --limit-rate vs. curl --limit-rate

Tags: wget, curl, rtorrent

I have a few huge data-files in a far-away galaxy. I need to download these, and it is likely to take a few days. While I want to make sure that all the data is downloaded safe and sound, uncompromised, I also need to ensure that I do not consume the entire bandwidth as other folks may need to access that machine remotely.

I have two alternatives methinks: `wget --limit-rate=amount` / `curl --limit-rate <speed>` or a cli torrent client `rtorrent`, `transmission` or something similar.

I am a noob, and would love to know what would be the advantages of one and the other. Also, is there any other means to get those monsterfiles downloaded properly?

Comment: Are the monster files compressed?

Comment: They are indeed. Targz methinks.

Comment: You could try using rsync: `rsync -chavzP --bwlimit=KBPS user@remote.host:/path/to/copy /path/to/local/storage` If you have SSH access to the server that hosts your files.

Comment: Rsync has an 'resume' option in case your download stops. Read more here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48298